# How to active a <li> in <ul> nested in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a sidebar menu, some `<li>` have sub-options that you see in the code, my question is when I click on one of these `<li>` sub-options I want it to be activated, even after Page load is also enabled.How should I do this?
This jQuery code I wrote only works for `<li>` without sub-options

```
<ul>
 <li>
 <a asp-page="/Index" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa- 
dashboard"></i><span> dashboard</span></a>
</li>
  <li class="has_sub">
   <a class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span>  
    users</span><span class="pull-right"><i class="md md- 
    add"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
     <li><a asp-page="/Account/Index"> user</a></li>
       <li><a asp-page="/AccountDelete/Index">  Delete
      </a></li>
     <li><a asp-page="/Accounts/Role/Index"> role </a></li>                                    
     </ul>
  </li> 
 </ul>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$("ul li a").each(function(){
 if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname){
   $(this).addClass("active");
 }
});
```

Comment: Before asking the question, I searched first but did not find the answer to my question

Comment: just to confirm, are the sub-option links clickable and routing as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `href` attribute in your logic, and that seems to be what is causing the issue for you.  Try looking for both href and asp-page attributes.

```js
function clearActiveClass(idx, elm) {
  let $elm = $(elm);

  $elm.removeClass("active");
}

function setActiveClassOnload(idx, elm) {
  let $elm = $(elm);

  if ($elm.attr("href") == window.location.pathname || $elm.attr("asp-page") == "/") {
    $elm.addClass("active");
  }
}

function setActiveClass(idx, elm) {
  let $elm = $(elm);

  $elm.addClass("active");
}

function registerClickHandlers(idx, elm) {
  let $elm = $(elm);

  $elm.click(onclickActiveClass);

  function onclickActiveClass(ev) {
    let $targetElm = $((ev || { target: this }).target);

    $("ul li .active").each(clearActiveClass);
    setActiveClass(-1, $targetElm);
  }
}

// inline execution -- so, do $(document).ready; Or, ensure is executed at bottom of page

$("ul li a").each(function(idx, elm) {
  clearActiveClass(idx, elm);
  setActiveClassOnload(idx, elm);
  registerClickHandlers(idx, elm);
});
```

```css
.active {
  font: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a asp-page="/Index" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
    <span>Dashboard</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="has_sub">
    <a class="waves-effect">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      <span>Users</span>
      <span class="pull-right"><i class="md md-add"></i></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a asp-page="/Account/Index">User</a></li>
      <li><a asp-page="/AccountDelete/Index">Delete</a></li>
      <li><a asp-page="/Accounts/Role/Index">Role</a></li>
      <li><a asp-page="/">Answer</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

in ref: comment on @mahdi-gholami answer

> the markup you are using is asp server-side code. It's dotnet application-specific, and it will require being compiled (can be runtime compilation) and served as markup for the user-agent/browser. the jQuery snippet is effectively using the address bar to determine current page. It isn't a snippet that toggles 'active' on click. but it is a snippet you would expect in a full page post (non SPA) application.

Comment: actually... these `asp-page` should render to `href` and the `asp-page` attribute would be removed after it's rendered... so, I don't think this going to be a good solution. your issue seems outside the scope of the information you've provided or what we can infer on from the question.

Comment: Updated snippet - I'm still unsure the scenario OP is/was in (and I'm not confident in this answer), but I wanted this answer to support registering click handlers on a persisted page while handling onpage load checks against address pathname -- as these are considerations to the answer.